# What is the easiest way to experimentally determine the center of mass of an irregular 3d object that has a non-uniform density?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, statics, experimental-technique

I want a method that can be done in a basic high-school lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a guitar, make a sea-saw mechanism

[image: seasaw]

You need a triangle and a plank with some guards so that it does not slide. The guards will give the cm error of your measurement.

place the guitar  on one side at the center and slide it until the sea saw balances. Draw a line on the side. Set it on the other side and balance again. Draw a line on that side . The two planes intersection contains the center of mass, and since the guitar is elongated and symmetric the half point on the intersection line is the center of mass.

For an asymmetric object where three sides can be defined, three planes can be found and their common intersect, within errors, is the center of mass.

Comment: +1; I did perform it many a times; it was really an amazing job for me to do when I was at mid-ten or so (then I didn't know about COG but I could visualise that point of _miracle-balancing_ by doing this). You brought me back my old nostalgia:)

Answer (score 2):

Suspend the object by a string from two distinct points. In each case trace the extended trajectory of the string through the object. It passes through the center of mass. Then the intersection of 2 (or more) different trajectories will give you the exact position of the COM.

Comment: Does this work for objects with non-uniform density? If so, why?

Comment: Also, you can't really point to that particular point because you can't really extrapolate the trajectory of a string _through_ the object. There is no way to accurately see the intersection of the trajectories.

Comment: Yes, it does work for non-uniform density, that's the whole point. If it didn't you'd have a torque from gravity rotating your body about the suspension point. Was standard demo when I was in school. One popular version: irregularly shaped piece of cardboard, possibly with extras glued to surface, suspend by edge, mark/draw trajectories on surface. Another possibility: fruit, no hard outer shell, use barbecue skewers or knitting needles to punch trajectory through. Check: hold object as close to intersection as possible, should be in indifferent equilibrium.

Comment: What if I need to find the center of mass of a guitar, or a toy car? There's no way to put barbecue skewers through these.

Comment: I guess you could use rulers as guides to extrapolate the string and guesstimate the exit points and/or the intersection, then guesstimate the COM position's depth. You'd have a more precise outcome if you could also use a 3d digital model of the object: only need suspension and exit points for each trajectory.